# how to implement apriori algorithm in h2o?

Tags: apriori, h2o

I'm a newbie in h2o and recently started implementing machine learning algorithms,but I can't find apriori algorithm implementation or required packages to implement the algorithm.
Can anybody suggest me if it is available in h2o?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not available in H2O.  Here is a list of algorithms in H2O: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/tutorials/datascience/DataScienceH2O-Dev.md